# Ansible points to an error with a non-existent parameter in the iptables module

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

Playbook:

```
- name: Изменение правил iptables 
  hosts: server01
  tasks:
   - name: Добавление правила
     ansible.builtin.iptables:
        chain: INPUT
        protocol: tcp
        destination_port: 80
        ctstate: NEW
        jump: ACCEPT
        comment: Allow HTTP
     become: yes
```

Output:

```
fatal: [server01]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (ansible.builtin.iptables) module: match_set_flagschain Supported parameters include:
```

I don't understand what the error is, this parmater is not in the playbook itself and it is not in the documentation

I tried to test the module and its behavior in the system

Answer (score 0):

> *I don't understand what the error is ...*

Error messages like `Unsupported parameters for (<moduleName>) module: <givenParameter>. Supported parameters include: <supportedParametersList>` are usually syntax errors of the module used.

> *... this parameter is not in the playbook itself ...*

Not within the question posted, maybe somewhere else.

> *... it is not in the documentation ...*

The documentation of [`iptables` module – Modify iptables rules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/iptables_module.html) show within the list of [Parameters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/iptables_module.html#parameters)

- [`match_set`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/iptables_module.html#parameter-match_set)
- [`match_set_flags`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/iptables_module.html#parameter-match_set_flags)

as well

- [`chain`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/iptables_module.html#parameter-chain)

So the message `Unsupported parameters for (ansible.builtin.iptables) module: match_set_flagschain` still indicates an syntax error.

Furthermore I wasn't able to reproduce an issue with a simple minimal playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: true
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - ansible.builtin.iptables:
      chain: INPUT
      protocol: tcp
      destination_port: 80
      ctstate: NEW
      jump: ACCEPT
      comment: Allow HTTP
```